# Is there any plugin in Jenkins to automatically merge the feature/dev branch to master after job build?

Tags: jenkins

i am using the github to create a PR , When a Pull Request is created the jenkins build is triggered

What I want:

The final step I want is to automatically merge and close the PR when jenkins has approved. I am using **Github pull request builder** plugin.

If you need any more information i will gladly provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [GitHub Pull Request Builder](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ghprb/) plugin provides the functionality that you need. In your Jenkins job configuration please scroll down to the **Post-build Actions** and add  **Github Pull Request Merger** from dropdown. Then configure it in a way that you need. Save the job configuration

Here are the screenshots
[image]
[image]